# Kangxi input only letting me type two keys before moving on? E.g I type RMMR for m4, but it gives me 叼可 instead?

Tags: cantonese, traditional-characters, input-methods

This is presumably a simple issue with my keyboard usage. A dropdown for characters is offered after typing RM, but I should be able to type RMMR and have it know I mean m4, right? I am using Traditional HONG KONG SAR keyboard layout on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you want to use Changjie 倉頡, but you are using Quick 速成 instead. Just go to the language settings and add the 倉頡 back should work.